# Given two points, construct a parallelepiped with a square base(length given)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

So I have been doing this for a while now, and I am afraid I am horribly overthinking this problem, so I came here for some fresh takes on this.

I want to obtain all the vertices of a [parallelepiped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XssmA.jpg) constructed between two points A and B, where at each point we have a square base of given length l.

I have attempted to solve this problem by finding a quaternion to rotate the vertices(as vectors) of a parallelepiped located at the origin, but I feel like there should be an easier solution to this

I don't know if this makes any sense, let me know how I can improve the question, I am just really overthinking this and need some help.

Comment: If all faces of the parallelepiped are squares then it is a cube. What do you mean by a parallelepiped constructed between two points? If you could make some diagrams, that might be more helpful.

Comment: @AlanAbraham I added a photo of a diagram, I am afraid it is not pretty but hope it helps)

Comment: Is it constrained to be a rectangular prism i.e. should the normals of the square bases be parallel to the line $AB$?

Comment: Also you mentioned overthinking the problem. What approaches have you tried? Can you include them in your question?

Comment: Yeah, they should be parallel

Comment: Well there are still infinite rectangular prisms since you can just rotate it about $AB$.

Comment: Let $\vec{v_x}=\vec{AB}\times \vec{i}$, $\vec{v_y}=\vec{AB}\times \vec{j}$, $\vec{v_z}=\vec{AB}\times \vec{k}$. At least one of these vectors is not zero-vector. Let this vector is $\vec{v}$. This vector is perpendicular to $\vec{AB}$. Let $\vec{v_1}=\frac{l}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|}$, $\vec{v_2}=\frac{\vec{v_1}\times \vec{AB}}{|\vec{AB}|}$, $\vec{v_3}=\frac{\vec{v_2}\times \vec{AB}}{|\vec{AB}|}$, $\vec{v_4}=\frac{\vec{v_3}\times \vec{AB}}{|\vec{AB}|}$. Let $\vec{AA_n}=\vec{v_n}$, $\vec{BB_n}=\vec{v_n}$ for $n=1,2,3,4$. Then $A_n$ and $B_n$ are vertices of parallelepiped.

Comment: I suppose that $A$ and $B$ are centers of square faces, $AB$ is perpendicular to square faces and there is no preferred parallelepiped between parallelepipeds satisfying given conditions.

Comment: Yeah I am aware that there are infinite possibilities, I just wanted any 1 given, I understand that the task is a lil abstract, but I have solved this using quaternions in the end

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu nice solution, seems to make sense, thank you sir